# I'm working with mongoose and nodejs, but not able to print what i want to

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
let somevar = candidate.find({}, {_id:0,name:1 });
console.log(somevar.map());
```

Current output which was not expected

```
Query {
...
    collectionName: 'candidates'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true,
  _userProvidedFields: { _id: 0, name: 1 }       
}
```

Im not able to understand the error, so want someone to explain me whats happening here.
What i expected it to do is

```
["name1","name2".....]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a query but not executing it. You need to either do:

```
let someVar = await candidate.find()
```

Or

```
candidate.find().exec(function(err, candidates){
  console.log(candidates)
});
```